# Netsuite - Submit a custom button

Tags: button, netsuite, suitescript

On a fulfilled record we have a custom button that needs to be clicked on after the item fulfilled record is saved. Is this possible via SuiteScript ?

Comment: Yes, you can script the following requirement: when an Item Fulfillment record is saved, trigger a custom function (this custom function can also be tied to a button).  Do you have any script work done already?

Comment: In a  AfterSubmit event script do the validation and load the button script , or transform  the button script into a AfterSubmit Script.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed... You can create buttons and validations on scripts...